# "Супер-супер-система" может писаться как что-либо прапрапра(дед)?

Tags: слитно-дефис

> Мною, человеком бессистемным, впервые была
>   разработана система-супер-система.

Так у автора, но, может, предложить ему что-то посимпатичней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мною, человеком бессистемным, впервые была разработана
>   система-супер-система.

Вообще-то супер - это приставка, вернее, префиксоид, пишется слитно:

*Мною, человеком бессистемным, впервые была разработана система - суперсистема.*

По-моему, нормально смотрится. Просто тире нужно отбить пробелами. А второй у вас был дефис, вот он и портил картину.

Comment: Люсенька, пожалуйста... https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453273/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0