# Завершение ересей, или Где должна закрыться скобка?

Tags: пунктуация

> Образы этой сцены знакомы верующим с IV века, и в доиконоборческий
>   период именно она являлась главным обозначением чуда Воскресения
>   Христова. В IX веке, после завершения ересей (то есть отрицания того,
>   что Христос был сыном человеческим, и снятия запрета на его
>   изображение), сценой, олицетворяющей Воскресение, признавалась
>   «Сошествие в Ад». Однако и много позже мы часто встречаем «Явление» во
>   фресковых циклах.

Кто на ком стоял?

...признавал**а**сь «Сошествие в Ад»? Не признавал**о**сь?

Comment: Я бы сказал *признавал**о**сь,* относя к "Сошествию".

Comment: "Завершение ересей" = ереси были _окончательно оформлены_ или автор хотел сказать, что они _прекратились_? После "признавалась" надо бы освежить видовое наименование произведения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В IX веке, после завершения ересей (то есть отрицания того, что
>   Христос был сыном человеческим, и снятия запрета на его изображение),
>   сценой, олицетворяющей Воскресение, признавалась «Сошествие в Ад».

Действительно, скобки всё перепутали, по смыслу: **после завершения ересей и снятия запрета на Его изображение**. Снятие запрета - это не ересь, к пояснению в скобках не относится. Чтобы не повторять имя, нужно просто написать Его - с большой буквы, это уже указание на Христа.
Думаю, чтобы вернуть ясность, надо так:

*В IX веке, после завершения ересей (то есть отрицания того, что Христос был сыном человеческим) и снятия запрета на **Е**го изображение, сценой, олицетворяющей Воскресение, признавал**о**сь «Сошествие в Ад».*

Или: *В IX веке, после завершения ересей (то есть отрицания того, что Христос был сыном человеческим) и снятия запрета на **Е**го изображение, сценой, олицетворяющей Воскресение, признавалась сцена  «Сошествие в Ад».*

Или: *"признавался эпизод"...*

Comment: Людмила, вынужден с Вами не согласиться. Здесь дело не в скобках. Автор просто неграмотно  построил  фразу. Ну или вообьще не своим делом занялся. Во-первых, византийское иконоборчество - не ересь вообще. Ни по каким канонам. А во-вторых, речь идет о **завершении** процесса отрицания богочеловеческой сущности Христа (что, кстати говоря, тоже не "ересь", а скорее наущение Антихриста)...

Comment: @behemothus иконоборчество не ересь? Ну-ну.

Comment: @edem  *иконоборчество не ересь?* - представьте себе, нет. А как вы вообще понимаете слово "ересь?".  Вот из Вики определение. Сознательное отклонение от считающегося кем-либо верным религиозного учения, предлагающее иной подход к религиозному учению.Тут дважды не вяжется. Иконоборчество, во-первых, не было отклонением, а было именно господствующим направлением.  Всякое отклонение от него было ересью. Но это в общем-то ерунда... Самое главное. Иконоборчество никаких догматов не затрагивало, никаких иных прочтений Евангелий не вносило. Это был лишь иной подход к отправлению самого культа.

Comment: @behemothus как я понимаю? Очень просто. Ересь — это прежде всего противоречие утверждениЯМ, положенным в основу какого-либо учения, и не обосновывающим саму себя с точки зрения этих самых утверждений.

Comment: Вики говорит, что иконоборчество было запрещено Вторым Никейским собором 787 года, возобновилось в начале IX века, и окончательно запрещено в 843 году[13]. Так что смотря когда и смотря с чьей точки зрения. Католики (ортодоксальные )запретили и признали ересью в 9 веке (до того было ведущим направлением), а лютеране ересью не считали никогда. Так что автор всё-таки сведущ в этих вопросах.

Answer (score 1):

Я могу только посоветовать автору разобраться со своими мыслями. Но если он считает все сказанное ересями (на его совести), то скобки стоят на месте. Для полного понимания не хватает, видимо, одного-двух слов.

В IX веке, после завершения ересей (то есть **окончания эпохи** отрицания того, что Христос был сыном человеческим, и снятия запрета на его изображение), сценой, олицетворяющей Воскресение, признавалась «Сошествие в Ад».

> ...признавалась «Сошествие в Ад»? Не признавалось?

Ну да, скорее уж "признавалось".
Хотя что он там имел в виду, трудно сказать.
Сошествие - признавал**о**сь. Сцена - признавал**а**сь. Но у сцены нет названия, она без кавычек. Если в кавычках, то это название **картины**. Автор опять что-то намудрил. Ему не корректор нужен, а литературный редактор...